# Javascript - why can't I get the array element at index 0?

Tags: javascript

Continuing my programming exercises and have got the following code to loop through my array and display the previous value (called from a html button). Seems to work fine until I get back to the first element in the array and then it displays one of my error handling messages and not the first element.

On trying to display the first element I'm triggering the displayError("No match found: There should have been one") else clause.

I assume it's something simple I'm missing.

Please could someone advise how to change my code to cope with element 0. Please don't suggest major code edits or other language variants as I'm new to Javascript and this will just confuse me.

```
    this.displayPrevious = function(){
    setSearchValues();
    /*console.log("Search values are " + searchValueName + "," + searchValueTheme + "," + searchValueReference + "," + searchValuePiece);
    console.log("Array length is " + legoSets.length);*/
    if(legoSets.length>0){
        for(let k=0; k < legoSets.length; k++ ){
            console.log("This is k " + k);
            if(legoSets[k].setName === searchValueName){
                console.log(legoSets[k].setName + "," + legoSets[k].setTheme + "," + legoSets[k].setReferenceNumber + "," + legoSets[k].setPieceCount);
                console.log("previous is " + legoSets[k-1].setName);
                if(legoSets[k].setTheme === searchValueTheme && legoSets[k].setReferenceNumber === searchValueReference && legoSets[k].setPieceCount === searchValuePiece){
                    console.log("Full match");
                    if((k-1)>=0){
                        setInnerHtml(k-1);
                        returnFields(displaySetName,displaySetTheme,displaySetReferenceNumber,displaySetPieceCount);
                    } else {
                        displayError("Array Out of Bounds");
                    }
                } else {
                    displayError("More than one set matched: Duplicate");
                }
            } else {
                displayError("No match found: There should have been one");
            }
        }
    } else {
        displayError("Array Out of Bounds");
    }
}
```

Full code available on https://github.com/Tufty0906/javascript_exercises
Look for the 01_class_capture_array files

Many thanks.

Comment: What is the value of `legoSets` and `searchValueName`?

Comment: _"Seems to work fine until I get back to the first element in the array..."_ - There's nothing in your question that would _"get back to the first element"_. What's the content of `legoSets` (one or two examples only)? What's the content of `searchValueName` and where does it come from? When and how is `this.displayPrevious()` called? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> [mcve]

Comment: `if((k-1)>=0){` seems to skip `k` = 0, shouldn't it be `if(k >= 0)` ?

Comment: Github link added